# Pipe ls output to get path of all directories

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to list all directories `ls -d *` in the current directory and list out all their full paths. I know I need to pipe the output to something, but just not sure what. I don't know if I can pipe the output to a `pwd` or something.

The desired result would be the following.

```
$ cd /home/
$ ls -d *|<unknown>
/home/Directory 1
/home/Directory 2
/home/Directory 3
```

`<unknown>` being the part which needs to pipe to `pwd` or something.

My overall goal is to create a script which will allow to me construct a command for each full path supplied to it. I'll type `build` and internally it will run the following command for each.

```
cd <full directory path>; JAVA_HOME=jdk/Contents/Home "/maven/bin/mvn" clean install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply:

```
$ ls -d $PWD/*/
```

Or

```
$ ls -d /your/path/*/
```

Comment: This works perfect! I have a followup question. Now that I can put `ls -d $PWD/*/` into my bash script, how could I go about iterating over each to run the command mentioned which does a change directory, sets the `JAVA_HOME` param and then runs `clean install`?

Comment: If your directories don't have spaces in them, a simple for loop should do.

Comment: You can loop over directories with spaces in them too, just don't use a Useless Use of Ls; http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls.  Instead, do `for d in $PWD/*/.; do whatever "$d"; done`.  The double quotes are important!  Always quote your variable interpolations.

Answer (score 1):

```
find `pwd` -type d -maxdepth 1 -name [^.]\*
```

Note: The above command works in bash or sh, not in csh.  (Bash is the default shell in linux and MacOSX.)

Comment: If you switch `-maxdepth 1` and `-type d`, you get rid of the warning. What is the purpose of the name option and the sed command?

Comment: The name option's argument is a regular expression which says "ignore the hidden files".  I'm removing the sed portion now since it's no longer necessary (the pwd prefix obviates removing "./" from the find output).

Comment: You don't need to mask the dot in the group. A dot as joker makes no sense in a group. Therefore, in a group, it doesn't work as a joker. However - the name parameter uses globbing, not regexes, so it doesn't work as joker though. ? is the joker for globbing.

Comment: The square brackets are a "character class". When the first character in the class is a hat (^), it means "characters NOT in this class".  I will remove the backslash, since it's not necessary to escape the dot in a character class.

Comment: Yes, `character class` is what I meant with `group`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -d $PWD/* | xargs -I{} echo 'cd {} JAVA_HOME=jdk/Contents/Home "/maven/bin/mvn" clean install' >> /foo/bar/buildscript.sh
```

will generate the script for u.

Answer (score 0):

Might I also suggest using `--` within your `ls` construct, so that `ls -d $PWD/*/` becomes `ls -d -- $PWD/*/` (with an extra `--` inserted)? This will help with those instances where a directory or filename starts with the `-` character:

```
/home/-dir_with_leading_hyphen/
/home/normal_dir/
```

In this instance, `ls -d */` results in:

```
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

However, `ls -d -- */` will result in:

```
-dir_with_leading_hyphen/      normal_dir/
```

And then, of course, you can use the script indicated above (so long as you include the `--` any time you call `ls`).

Answer (score 0):

No piping neccessary:

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%H/%f\n"
```

to my surprise, a command in the print statement works too:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "$(pwd)/%f\n"
```